# Suspicious process running under user postfix

Tags: firewall

I have a VPS on which I have installed ConfigServer Firewall for about a year now. This morning I started to receive this kind of emails from CFS. I've checked mail.log and auth.log and everything seems to be ok, no strange login to the server.

Is this something I should worry about?

(I've redacted my vps IP)

> Time:    Tue Mar  5 20:40:43 2024 +0200 PID:     1983320 (Parent
> PID:1089935) Account: postfix Uptime:  735 seconds
>
> Executable:
>
> /usr/lib/postfix/sbin/smtpd
>
> Command Line (often faked in exploits):
>
> smtpd -n smtps -t inet -u -c -o stress= -s 2 -o
> smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o smtpd_tls_security_level=may -o
> smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
>
> Network connections by the process (if any):
>
> tcp: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:465 -> 46.148.40.149:3036

Answer (score 0):

The process is a standard part of Postfix – smtpd is literally the process that handles inbound SMTP connections. The path looks normal for a Postfix subprocess.

The connection looks like an inbound SMTPS connection from Iran; its duration of 12 minutes is definitely unusual for SMTP, so I would assume it's busy cracking your passwords or sending spam. (I'm not 100% sure whether Postfix smtpd keeps running across multiple connections; if it does, the uptime would be normal.)

Comment: thanks for reply. what worried me was that network connection to an Iran IP. but when I looked for that IP in server logs, every login attempt from that IP was marked as failed.